# Yajra data tables order by column

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I'm using yajra/laravel-datatables plugin to get create datatables in laravel. This is my code.

```
$data = MyModel::latest()
                ->where('subject', 3)
                ->get();

return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
```

This is my js code

```
var table = $('#empTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        serverMethod: 'post',
        ajax: "{{ url('my url') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'reference_no', name: 'reference_no'}
        ]
    });
```

But unfortunately data is not sorted and I'm not getting latest data first ('id' 'desc'). It would be a great help if someone has a solution

Comment: The issue is most likely in your javascript code where you initialize the dataTable. Could you add it to your question.

Comment: @Remul Sure I added

Comment: Could you try adding  `order: [],` to your javascript, this way dataTable wont sort on the first column, therefore displaying it the way you return it form the controller.

Comment: @Remul Tried order: [[ 1, "desc" ]] bud didn't work :'(

Comment: @Remul Sorry It worked and if you can add it as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the default sorting from dataTable in order to achieve the desired result:

```
var table = $('#empTable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    serverMethod: 'post',
    order: [],
    ajax: "{{ url('my url') }}",
    columns: [
        {data: 'reference_no', name: 'reference_no'}
    ]
});
```

By default dataTable will sort the table by the first column, so the `reference_no` in your case, but since you are providing the inital ordering from your data, you can set the default ordering to an empty array.